# How to add page to organization with liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to create new pages for a organization in liferay 6.1 ,but in the organization configuration pages, I couldn't find a link or place to add new page. Where I can do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the control panel.
- Go to the Users and Organizations pane.
- Click your organization.
- On the right, click Organization Site.
- Check "Create".
- Select a Site Template or leave as None.
- Save.
- On the Left, there is a drop down with a list of sites. Click your Organization.
- Click on "Site Pages"
- Add pages.

Comment: Hi , you are 99% right except for an important thing missing which is you have to go to edit mode first before clicking Organization Site. Thank u a lot.